# How do I convert this timestamp into a MySQL DATETIME object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm fetching GPS data to display on a Google map in a Rails 2.3.8 app.

The timestamp for each data point is in this format:

```
2011-08-14T09:23:11.000Z
```

I need to get that into MySQL as a DATETIME object so I can then sort and filter the track points by time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Most databases should accept an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) timestamp as-is for a datetime or timestamp column. What happens when you try to use that string?

Comment: I wasn't even aware that was an ISO 8601 timestamp so I was storing it at a string. I was asking how to convert so I could stores it as DATETIME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord usually will convert this for you when you save your object into the database. If for some reason, you're bypassing AR, you can convert it to db format via:

```
"2011-08-14T09:23:11.000Z".to_s(:db)
```

Comment: Switched column from VARCHAR to DATETIME and I'm done!!! I wasn't aware that was a standard format. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Time.parse "2011-08-14T09:23:11.000Z"
```